# What is the conditional distribution function of the moment when the first event happens when the total number of event is given?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose books are getting missing from a library as a Poisson process $N(t)$ with intensity $\lambda$. Suppose we know that at the moment $t$, $N(t) = n$.

> 1. What is the conditional distribution function of the moment $W_1$ when the first book was missing?

What I did was using the theorem on page 298 from [this link](http://matap.dmae.upm.es/WebpersonalBartolo/Probabilidad/KarlinTaylorIntrodStochModeling.pdf). I treat $W_1$ as the minimum of the ordered statistics of $(U_1, U_2, \dotsc, U_n)$ which follow uniform distribution, get the answer and take the derivative.

$$\begin{align}
&P(W_1 \leq z \mid N(t) = n) \\
=\ &P(\min(U_1, U_2, \dotsc, U_n) \leq z) \\
=\ &1 - P(\min(U_1, U_2, \dotsc, U_n) \geq z) \\
=\ &1 - \prod_{i=1}^n P(U_i \geq z) \\
=\ &1 - \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - P(U_i \leq z)) \\
=\ &1 - (1 - z)^n
\end{align}$$

Can anyone please tell me if this is correct? To be honest, I don't think it is right. Because the derivative is $n(1-z)^{n-1}$ which can be bigger than 1!

> 2. What is the conditional expected value of $W_1$? Is it different from $E(W_1)$?

I don't see the difference.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @joriki :(..............Thought I did my best................

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your calculation is correct. It doesn't matter that the density can be bigger than $1$; it's just a density, not a probability. Now you just have to take into account that the events are uniformly distributed over $[0,t]$, not $[0,1]$.

Yes, the conditional expectation of $W_1$ is different from the unconditional one. The unconditional one depends on $\lambda$, and the conditional one doesn't (as it's determined by the conditional distribution that you calculated).

The simplest way to get the expectation of the first order statistic of $n$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables is to add an $(n+1)$-th variable (also i.i.d.) and take it as the point at which to break the circle formed by identifying the beginning and end of the range. By symmetry, every segment between the $n+1$ variables has expected length $\frac t{n+1}$, and the first of these segments is $W_1$.

Comment: For the first question, is the CDF $$1-(1-\frac{x}{t})^n$$?

Comment: @YilinWang: Yes. You can use `\left` and `\right` to let the parentheses adjust to the size of their content.

Comment: What is the conditional expected value? I can not find it. Help

Comment: @YilinWang: I derived it in the answer.